# VueJS Component vue-multiselect-listbox

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use this beautiful component located here https://abhimediratta.github.io/vue-multiselect-listbox

but I'm having some problems. I am not too good with VueJS and having problems trying to get this to work.

I am trying to follow the tutorial.

```
App.vue

<template>
    <h2>Example</h2>

    <h3>List Options</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="['Alabama', 'California']"></v-multiselect-listbox>


    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code">
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Group List options</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al', group: 'US'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal', group: 'US'}, {label: 'British Columbia', code: 'bc', group: 'Canada'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           :reduce-group-property="(option) => option.group">
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Select/Deselect All Buttons</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           :show-select-all-buttons="false">
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Highlight Difference from the original input</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           search-input-class="custom-input-class"
                           highlight-diff>
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Search Input Placeholder</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           search-options-placeholder="Search states"
                           selected-options-placeholder="Search selected states">
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Empty Listbox Placeholder</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           no-options-text="No states"
                           selected-no-options-text="No states selected">
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Empty Search Placeholder</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           no-options-found-text="No state found"
                           no-selected-options-found-text="No selected state found">
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Hide Search Input</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           no-options-found-text="No state found"
                           no-selected-options-found-text="No selected state found"
                           hide-search-inputs>
    </v-multiselect-listbox>

    <h3>Style Search Input</h3>
    <v-multiselect-listbox :options="[{label: 'Alabama', code: 'al'}, {label: 'California', code: 'cal'}]"
                           :reduce-display-property="(option) => option.label"
                           :reduce-value-property="(option) => option.code"
                           search-input-class="custom-input-class">
    </v-multiselect-listbox>


</template>

<script>
import vMultiselectListbox from 'vue-multiselect-listbox'
import 'vue-multiselect-listbox/dist/vue-multi-select-listbox.css';

export default {
  name: 'Paste-test',
  components: { 'v-multiselect-listbox': vMultiselectListbox },
  data () {
    return {
      selected: '',
      options: ['10001', '10002', '10003', '10004', '10005', '10006', '10007', '10008', '10009', '10010'],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    parse_clipboard(content) {
        var arr = content.split(/[\s,]+/)
        var trimmed = '';
        var results = arr.filter(element => {
            trimmed = element.trim();

            if (trimmed.length) {
                return trimmed;
            }
        });

        return results
    },

    handlePaste(evt) {
        var data = evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        console.log('TwoPaneMultiSelect pasted data=', data);

        evt.preventDefault();

        var parsed_data = this.parse_clipboard(data);
        console.log('TwoPaneMultiSelect parsed_data=', parsed_data);

        this.options = parsed_data;
        this.selected = parsed_data;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
main.js

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

All it renders is this:

```
Example
List Options
```

And this error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: t._self is undefined
    w MultiSelect.vue:1
    renderComponentRoot runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:830
    componentUpdateFn runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5785
    run reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
    update runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5898
    setupRenderEffect runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5906
    mountComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5696
    processComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5649
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5124
    mountChildren runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5368
    processFragment runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5583
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5098
    componentUpdateFn runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5792
    run reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178
    update runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5898
    setupRenderEffect runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5906
    mountComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5696
    processComponent runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5649
    patch runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5124
    render runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:6416
    mount runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:3851
    mount runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1453
    <anonymous> main.js:4
    js app.js:39
    __webpack_require__ app.js:103
    __webpack_exports__ app.js:1225
    O app.js:149
    <anonymous> app.js:1226
    <anonymous> app.js:1228
MultiSelect.vue:1
```

I am using VueJS3.

Thanks!

I tried following the tutorial.

Comment: You probably didn't install the Vue 3 "compatible" version which isn't the default version on npm, you have to specify the version when installing with `npm install vue-multiselect-listbox@1.0.0-1`.  Once you do that, you'll encounter the same errors [other people have reported](https://github.com/abhimediratta/vue-multiselect-listbox/issues/18) with the Vue 3 version.  It's not an active or well maintained library.  Someone else made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/arnonrdp/pen/yLQMdgv) replicating the functionality from scratch.  I would just use that.

Comment: Ah that must be it. Many thanks! I have found that codepen as well, am working on turning it into a component and adding a few features. Thanks again!

Comment: Consider making an answer according to [answer] to share your insights in this problems solution.